# My app's deploy target is iOS 5.1 but my friend's iPad can't open my app, she's using iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios

My app is in App Store so that means my app has passed Apple's review but when my friend install and download the app she couldn't even see the splash screen and it crashed right after she tapped the app icon. What can be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Get the console log for the app and post the log in your question. To get the console log you'll need to connect the iPad to Xcode and use the organizer.

Comment: Get the crash report. Did you test your app on a device with 5.1? Or at least test in the 5.1 simulator? Most likely you are using a 6.x framework or API and you try to use it under 5.x.

Comment: She installed the app from the app store and she doesn't even have a Mac. How do I get the console log from there?

Comment: I haven't tested my app on iOS 5.1 device. Maybe that's the problem. I thought when I set the deploy target to 5.1 XCode will find the errors and warnings for me during deployment but it doesn't seem to do it thoroughly.

Comment: Setting the deploy target to iOS 5.1 won't find errors for you. It just ensures that your app has the glue code needed for that iOS version. You'll need to run against the iOS 5.1 or 5.0 simulator *at least*. (Best if you test on an actual iPad running 5.1.)

Comment: you need to change base sdk to test against 5.1 for compile time

Comment: @newguy: to get her crash logs, have her connect her iphone to her pc and look for the logs described in this post: http://bjango.com/help/crashlog/

Comment: Thanks guys. I have to test it on actual iPad not on simulators because some of the APIs that connect to YouTube services can't run on iOS simulator. Crash report is a good idea but my friend is not tech savvy so this is a dead end. I think I will try to test my app on devices running different iOS versions next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Here is the meat of your crash log. Based on the error it appears that @ThomasW and @rahul-vyas are correct that the deployment target inside your Build Settings is likely set to iOS6.x. I would recommend checking both the Target and the Project settings to make sure they're set to iOS5.1.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/B4F5424C-1593-4150-9AD0-6CF3FE3BD3E5/TubeNoStop.app/TubeNoStop
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  Dyld Version: 199.6

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x2fe2a080 dyld_fatal_error + 0
1   dyld                            0x2fe2cefc dyld::halt(char const*) + 72
2   dyld                            0x2fe2cfda dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 214
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x36aa83ec dyld_stub_binder + 12
```

Comment: Autolayout is another common gotcha

Comment: Thanks D80Buckeye. I haven't used ACFacebookAppIdKey or Autolayout. My app can be found here:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id668915517?mt=8

Comment: Answer updated - check out the recommended settings mentioned.

Comment: I guess you are right. I set the deployment target in `Targets` tab to 5.1 but forgot to set the deployment target in `Project` tab to 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have your friend install this: [iPhone Configuration Utility 3.6.2 for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1466)

She can use that to email the crash report to you. Then import the crash report into the organiser in xcode, and "symbolicate" it to find where it crashed.

But before doing any of that, run it in the iOS 5.1 Simulator in Xcode. Chances are it will crash there too. If you don't have the 5.1 simulator you can install it from settings (it uses a couple GB of disk space)